# Verification of the Meaning of "omnia mea dicionem sunt"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I have formulated my own expression in latin, *omnia mea dicionem sunt*, which I would like to get verified actually interprets to what I think it does (as I am no latin expert). Here's the breakdown of what I mean:

1. "Omnia" is "all or everthing: totality".
2. "mea" is possessive "my" (e.g., I think of it like "my house": I own or possess the "house").
3. "Dicionem" ("Dicio"), in this case, I believe is "under control, authority, power, rule, or domain of something" (the "something" being defined in the sentence "dicio" is utilized in).
4. "sunt" is the verb "to be" in latin.

Therefore, I interpret *omnia mea dicionem sunt* as "All/everthing that is mine is under my authority, control, or power".

Is my translation correct? Are the conjugations and such correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does not quite work that way: *dicio* means “authority, rule, power,” so “under the authority” or “in the power” would be *sub mea dicione* or *in mea dicione*. Other than that, your sentence is generally fine, but I would point out:

- If you want to refer to “all my possessions,” then it is probably more common to say *omnia mea bona*.
- *Dicio* seems to usually refer to political/administrative rule or power, especially over regions or people. A more general term would be *potestas*.
- You do not say *whose* authority/control/power, and I do not think it follows effortlessly from context. You could throw in another *mea*, but a more elegant solution would be to say *in potestate habeo* (or, if it was not in your power before, *in potestatem habeo* = *in potestatem accepi in eaque habeo*).

So I would say: *Omnia mea bona in potestate habeo.*

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to express the idea of something being under your authority (as opposed to you just owning them). The most basic is the word *potestatis*. So, for example,

***...in potestatem Romanorum transiit*** (it passed under the authority of the Romans)

You can also use the word auctoritas:

***...ad unius se auctoritatem contulerunt*** (they put themselves under the authority of one person)

***...ad P. Lentuli auctoritatem a senatu profectam Roma contenderat...*** (...he left Rome under the authority of P. Lentulus which had been granted by the Senate)

The word dicio can be used to indicate authority:

***dicionem populi Romani sese tradebant*** (They put themselves under the power of the Roman people)

The way that you say "all my stuff" in the sense of wealth is ***omnis mea ops*** or ***mea res omnis***. The way that you refer to petty possessions and everyday things is the neuter noun *bonum* (a good). For example,

***ego huc bona mea degessi*** (I brought my stuff here)

As Koppehel says above, the Romans did not typically think of possessions being under the "power" or authority of somebody. In Latin, power is wielded over people, not inanimate objects. However, there is a special word in Latin which is used to describe control over property and that word is the 4th declension *manus* (the HAND, kind of like THE CLAW in Toy Story). So, for example, we have this statement from Cicero:

***Cum mulier viro in manum convenit, omnia quae mulieris fuerunt viri fiunt dotis nomine.*** (When a woman goes under the hand of a man, then all of the woman's belongings become the man's by way of a dowry).

Now, before attacking the main thrust of your motto, there is another important idiom to be aware of. That is you can use meus to indicate something belonging to you, but when speaking emphatically, the word *noster* is used. In other words, noster usually means "ours", but in an emphatic or emphasized context, it means "mine". So, now that we know this, we can put together a Roman motto to get your meaning:

***Omnis res nostra mihi in manu [est].*** (Everything of mine is under my power.)

Note that you can omit the *est* as understood to increase the poetic effect of the motto.

Finally, I should probably explain why we have *mihi* instead of *meo*. In English we say "in my hand", but the Romans did not think of it that way. They thought of it as "in the hand which is belonging to me" and so the Dative case is used in situations like this. So, for example, take this sentence from Sallust:

***...neque mihi in manu fuit Iugurtha qualis foret*** (...and it was not in my power to shape the character of Jugurtha.)

So, we see in this sentence from Sallust a very similar kind of idea which you want to express and we see how Sallust uses the phrase *mihi in manu*, not *in manu meo*. This is the challenge of Latin: to learn the thinking behind expressions like this.

Now, before leaving this subject, I will throw one more idiom at you. In Latin, you can refer to your entire household and everything in it by using the word *penates*. Usually Penates means the household gods, what takes care of your stuff, but figuratively it can mean the household and its belongings and furniture and dependents inside of it. So, an alternative way to state your motto, if you are just talking about your household is:

***Penates nostri mihi in manu*** (All my household is under my power.)

Comment: How about reading *mihi in manu est* as "is to me in hand" instead of "[is] in the hand which is belonging to me"? I always thought of datives like this expressing benefit morning than possession.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I think that is fine. The problematic thing is that we don't really have an equivalent thought pattern in English, so any rendering tends to be an approximation at best.

Comment: I don't think I've heard of *noster* as an "emphatic" version of *meus*, but if it was used, I would think that *mihi* would also become plural *nobis*. Without context though the default reading would be a true plural "ours", so it's probably better avoided in this case.

Comment: @TKR When speaking emphatically of personal possessions, it normal to use noster. Hae nuces nostrae sunt!!! (These toys are mine!!!) It is somewhat colloquial, but in the situation of a motto, as we have here, this would the most apropos way to say it for a real Roman.

Comment: Do you have any classical examples of this emphatic use? BTW note that since *penates* is plural, it would be *penates nostri*.

Comment: @TKR when penates is used to mean the household, it treated as a collective plural and so singular adjectives are used. As just one example of using noster, in the "Hercules" of Seneca, at one point Hercules gives a speech beginning "Miserere genitor..." (Have pity father) and at the end of the speech, talking about his guilt for his transgressions, he says, "Tacuere, nostrum est" (They are silent, it is mine.) meaning the guilt for killing Eunomus is his alone (nostrum est = it is mine). That is just one example, I could cite many others, it is a normal and common usage.

Comment: "when penates is used to mean the household, it treated as a collective plural and so singular adjectives are used." Not actually true, of course.

Comment: @Cairnarvon I switched to the plural adjective because it seems that the standard practice was to treat it as plural, even when used to mean a home.

Comment: Yes, the usage of *nos* with a singular reference is common, but I don't think it's emphatic in any sense.